# after submitting form it keeps on making POST requests only

Tags: python, html, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using flask-wtforms, flask-sqlalchemy and flask-bootstrap for my project. I can't for the life of me, understand why after submitting the form, it doesn't redirect to the page I set it to. 
Here is the python part:

```
@app.route('/newevent', methods=['GET', 'POST']) #TAGGED
@login_required
def newevent():
    form = NewEvent()
    msgs = ''
    if request.method=='POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        check = Event.query.filter_by(eventid=form.eventid.data).first()
        if check is None:
            db.session.add(
                Event(eventid=form.eventid.data, 
                      eventName=form.eventName.data, 
                      eventDate=form.eventDate.data, 
                      allocation=form.allocation.data, 
                      Event_orgCode=current_user.orgCode))
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('adminevents'))
        elif check.eventid == form.eventid.data:
            msgs = 'Event already exists!'
            return render_template('events_new.html', form=form, msgs=msgs)
    return render_template('events_new.html', form=form, msgs=msgs)
```

now here is the html part:

```
{% block content %}
{% with msg = get_flashed_messages() %}
<h1>Create New Event</h1>
    <h3> {{ msgs }} </h3>
<div class="input-event">
<form class="form form-horizontal" action="{{ url_for('newevent') }}" method="POST" role="form">
<dl>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.eventid, placeholder="Pick a 4-digit ID e.g., 0042") }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.eventName, placeholder="Name your event") }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.eventDate) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.allocation, placeholder="Enter budget allocation") }}
</dl>
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Add">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='/adminevents'">
</form>

</div>
{% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have a similar function called `newbudget`. It is quite similar to the code in question and works perfectly fine. Please help I'm at my wit's end already.

Comment: solved this silly problem lul. i think it was because I was calling app.run() on two separate files and imported them in each other.